# Problem with PHP Session Object

Tags: php, session, moodle

I am facing some problem with my php session. I have deployed a plugin for file management in my moodle application.

The new plugin home page is behaving unexpectedly and is destroying the actual session of my application and is generating new `session_id()`.

Also when I am trying to view session contents using `print_r($_SESSION)`, it is showing 
"PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name` has nothing to do with session regeneration.

This behaviour appears when you (or your cms/framework/whatever you have) call `session_start()` before each serialized object's class definition has been parsed.

So you need to include all classes before you started session.